# Dynamically set style sheet based on routing in a multi-tenant Angular 5 application

Tags: angular

I have a multi-tenant app that's being re-implemented in Angular 5.  Each client has color and font preferences.

Client is determined by the routing e.g. 
 - www.mydomain.com/client1/salesData
 - www.mydomain.com/client2/salesData
 - etc.

I have a default.css stylesheet with styles like:

```
.clientBackground { color: white; }
```

And would like to have client stylesheets like:

```
client1.css {
.clientBackground { color: blue; }
}

client2.css {
.clientBackground { color: green; }
}
```

Then, use the appropriate style sheet based on the client in the incoming route.

Any ideas on how this might be done?  The old system (Microsoft MVC) uses style "bundles" that could be optionally included based on client.

EDIT 1/24/18
Wound up taking a different approach than originally expected.  Identified the specific style attributes that would change by client e.g. color, backgroundColor, font-family, etc.  and placed these in a class (ClientStyles).  Then created child classes for each client ... and a factory to return the proper class given a client ID.
Then created a custom directive [client-styles].  It takes a comma-delimited string of style attributes (e.g. 'color,font-family') , finds these attributes in the ClientStyles class and applies them to the element.  As follows:

```
import { Attribute, Directive, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Inject, HostBinding, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    import { ClientStyles } from '../../../models/ClientStyles';
    import * as clientStyleDefs from '../../../models/client/ClientStyleDefs';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[client-styles]'
    })
    export class ClientStylesDirective implements OnInit {

      clientCode: string;
      clientStyles: ClientStyles = new ClientStyles();
      inputStyles: string[];
      sInputStyles: string;
      element: ElementRef;

      // client-styles takes a comma-delimited list of style attributes
      // to be set with client values 
      // (or defaults if client value for the attribute is not specified) 
      constructor(
        el: ElementRef, @Attribute("client-styles") styleString: string,
        @Inject(StateProvider) private _state: Observable<State>) { 
          this.element = el;
          this.inputStyles = styleString.split(',');
          this.sInputStyles = styleString;
        }

      ngOnInit() {
        this._state.subscribe(x => {
          this.clientCode = x.criteria.clientCode;      
        });

        this.clientStyles = clientStyleDefs.getClientStyles(this.clientCode);
        this.setStyles();
      }

      setStyles() {
        for (let prop in this.clientStyles) {
          // If property is in string, update that property in the element style
          if (this.sInputStyles.indexOf(prop) >= 0 && this.clientStyles[prop] != null) {
            // Heading and text font families - set the fontFamily
            if (prop == "headingFontFamily" || prop == "textFontFamily") {
              this.element.nativeElement.style["fontFamily"] = this.clientStyles[prop];
            }
            else {
              this.element.nativeElement.style[prop] = this.clientStyles[prop];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a global variable that determine the client type according to the active domain, you can do that as a service. 
The the rest of the styling can easily be done by an ngIf then ngStyle>

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an ideal use case for using router properties. This is how you can do it:

Go to your component which is responsible for rendering the required view and do this -

```
color: string;
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.setUpEvents();
}

private setUpEvents(): void {
    this.router.subscribe((value: any) => this.onNext(value)); //as router returns an observable so you need to subscribe
}

private onNext(value: any): void {
    console.log(value); //this will give you the path which has been activated and based on this you can initialize your style variable
    this.color = 'green'; //just for the sake of understanding. change it according to your need. And you can have many other css properties set here
}
```

Now inside your view make use of NgStyle, something like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': color}"></div>
```

Comment: Great tip.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, think you need to subscribe to router events ... this.router.events.subscribe ...